# Capture Images of Video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am playing a video from the server using the **AVPlayer**.

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now i want to capture the multiple images,While the video is playing and save it.
How Can i Do it..?

Comment: You want to create thumbnail of that video or multiple images from the video?

Comment: Multiple images of the Video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code,You can get thumbnail from video by using this

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:URl];
        AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
        CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        NSData *imagedata = [self compressImage:thumbnail];
        UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];//this is image from video at time interval 1 second
```

You can get multiple image to set multiple timeinterval

Comment: can u ckeck thumbnail is nil or not in debug??

Comment: thumbnail is not nil

Comment: this is ur thumbnail at timeinterval 1,and you can get more image t change

Comment: by using  CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, timeinterval);

Answer (score 0):

There exist very easier way to get frames from video using `MPMoviePlayerController`. Following code fetches image at `time:5`

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
        initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someVideo.mp4"]];
UIImage *singleFrameImage = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:5 
        timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

For obtaining multiple images from video, following implementation can be used.

1) Register for Notification to receive Image when each request is processed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
```

2) Initialize `MPMoviePlayerController` with required time's to get images.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
        initWithContentURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"someVideo.mp4"]];
NSNumber time1 = 15;
NSNumber time2 = 16;
NSNumber time3 = 17;
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:time1,time2,time3,nil];
[movie requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:times timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

3) Selector to receive image

```
-(void)MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification: (NSNotification*)note
{
    NSDictionary * userInfo = [note userInfo];
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
}
```

Comment: How can i do it with AVPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayer..?

Comment: is there any specific need to use AVPlayer?

Comment: Yes there is a need